# Changing metadata of audio file

Tags: python-3.x, audio

I have a small program for downloading youtube videos from playlist as an .mp3
I get the .mp3 file but sometimes they even have a title with the name of downloading website(yt5s.com):
[Image of file details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfVax.png)

I want to fix this problem by either removing the title or changing the title.
I tried:

```
from tinytag import TinyTag, TinyTagException

tracks = []
for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".mp3",".m4a",".flac",".alac")):
            tracks.append(name)
            try:
                temp_track = TinyTag.get(root + "\\" + name)
                print(temp_track.artist, "-", temp_track.title)
            except TinyTagException:
                print("Error")
```

But I only managed to print out the artist and title.

Comment: have you tried SOX? http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxi.html

Comment: @Pete Trcka I read the documentation and I didn't find there anything mentioning changing the title.

Comment: With Sox I was able to convert numpy into .waw / .mp3. I thought that set artist or track name will be possible as well. But no personal experience with this. Sorry.

Comment: I wasn't asking the right questions. But I finally found the right modul eyed3

Comment: can you provide working code and accept as answer?

Comment: okay but it's a really primitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the right module eyed3.
This changes the title of every song in the directory:

```
import eyed3
import os

files = os.listdir(path)
for _ ,file in enumerate(files):
    audiofile = eyed3.load(os.path.join(path, file))
    audiofile.tag.title = "Title"
    audiofile.tag.save()
```

You might want this:

```
from eyed3.id3.frames import ImageFrame
audiofile.tag.images.set(ImageFrame.FRONT_COVER, open(path2+file,'rb').read(), 'image/jpeg')
audiofile.tag.album = "Album"
audiofile.tag.album_artist = Artist
audiofile.tag.artist = Artist
```

Also, I met a few bugs resulting in me not seeing the cover of a song.

- When album_artist and artist weren't the same person. When there was
- more than one song in the same album with a different cover.

Also, it prints out message "Lame tag CRC check failed" but it doesn't do anything.